# bash script checking if file is binary or text using perl?

Tags: bash, perl

Can someone explain how this bash script piece works?

```
is_text_file() { 
    perl -e 'exit((-B $ARGV[0])?1:0);' "$1"
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl has file type test operators, which this invokes on its first arg. It then uses a ternary operator to convert True/False to a shell status 0 (isTxt) or 1 (not). The function has no explicit return value, so it returns the status of the perl command itself. Bash itself is doing almost nothing here.

```
-T  File is an ASCII or UTF-8 text file (heuristic guess).
-B  File is a "binary" file (opposite of -T).
```

Note carefully the word "guess".

Comment: ref. https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#-X-FILEHANDLE

Comment: ok, I think I got it.  -e means to execute a command. The command is `exit()` which exits the interpreter after running the `-B $ARGV[0])?1:0` and $ARGV[0] is the argument passed to it by the `$1` and the quotes are single quotes not backquotes.  How did it know to tie $1 as an input to exit ?

Comment: @user3161924, `$1` is the first arg to the shell function, it's passed as an arg to Perl which uses `$ARGV[0]` to hold the first arg to the script. (Same idea, different name in the two languages.) The Perl script calls the `-B` operator/function on that, fixes the returned value into 1 or 0, and passes that to `exit()`.

Comment: okay, so items outside the single quotes are parameters to the command after the -e.  Thanks!